# как загрузить фикстуры basic Yii2

Tags: yii2

> Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Invalid
>   fixture namespace: "tests\unit\fixtures". Please, check your
>   FixtureController::namespace parameter'
>
> in
>   /var/www/dnipro/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/console/controllers/FixtureController.php:519

```
namespace app\tests\fixtures;

use yii\test\ActiveFixture;

class TypeFixture extends ActiveFixture
{
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\Type';

    public $dataFile = 'tests\fixtures\data\type.php';
}
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Я хочу загрузить фейковые данные в базу. Когда в консоль пишу php yii fixture/load TypeFixtures мне выдает ошибку  Exception 'yii\base\InvalidConfigException' with message 'Invalid fixture namespace: "tests\unit\fixtures". Please, check your FixtureController::namespace parameter'